# How to use ^/$ if it's already used as a delimiter for regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

```
$regex = '$....$'

$regex = '^...^'
```

In the above two cases,how to use `^/$` to match the beginning/end of a string?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character as [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). But you shouldn’t use characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions.

So you could use the `~` if you don’t want to use `/`:

```
'~^/$~'
```

Comment: Bingo. Just use a different delimiter. I like @.

Comment: So it's impossible to use `$` both for delimiter and reserve its meaning for regex?

Comment: That's what happens when you use a special character as your delimiter. Why are you wedded to a specific one?

Answer (score 0):

just do escaping ?

```
$str='^...^';
preg_match("/^\^.*\^$/",$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: You didn't use `^/$` as delimiter