# How to include "#" in preg_replace?

Tags: php, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use ^/$ if it's already used as a delimiter for regex in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477801/how-to-use-if-its-already-used-as-a-delimiter-for-regex-in-php)

If I put "#" on preg_replace, it gives error. How can I include "#" in preg_replace ?

```
$document = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z 0-9,.?$@!&;]#i', '', $document);
```

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php): *"If the delimiter needs to be matched inside the pattern it must be escaped using a backslash."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You escape it

```
$document = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z 0-9,.?$@!&;\#]#i', '', $document);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use different delimiters.

```
/[^A-Za-z 0-9,.?$@!&;#]/
```

Answer (score 1):

By escaping it like `\#`. Also look at [this](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2.png)